# Count the number of unique elements of a list of tuples regardless of order in Python

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list that contains tuples in the form:

```
[('s1', 's2'),('s3','s32')...('s2','s1')]`
```

How can I count the number of distinct tuples, considering that the order is not important?

Example: `('s1','s2')` is the same as `('s2','s1')`

Answer (score 6):

Using [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`frozenset`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#frozenset):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(map(frozenset, [('s1', 's2'),('s3','s32'), ('s2','s1')]))
Counter({frozenset(['s2', 's1']): 2, frozenset(['s3', 's32']): 1})
```

To get keys as tuples:

```
>>> c = Counter(map(frozenset, [('s1', 's2'),('s3','s32'), ('s2','s1')]))
>>> {tuple(s): count for s, count in c.most_common()}
{('s2', 's1'): 2, ('s3', 's32'): 1}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using [frozenset](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#frozenset) to normalize your distinct tuples. And then checking the amount of items in the resulting set:

```
>>> l = [('s1', 's2'), ('s3','s32'), ('s2','s1')]
>>> len(set(map(frozenset, l)))
2
```