# Collections.counter of list of tuples regardless of order in python

Tags: python, list, collections, counter

I have a significant number of list of tuples in the form:

```
d1 = [('s1', 's2'),('s3','s32')...]
....
dn = [('s2', 's1'),('s3','s32')...]
```

Up to now I was using collections.Counter to add the counts for each tuple, but I realized that in this case the tuples ('s1', 's2') and ('s2', 's1') are considered distinct, but this is something that I do not want.

To be clear what I want to obtain is:

```
result = {('s1', 's2'):2,('s3','s32'):2...}`
```

regardless of the order of elements inside the tuple.

I am looking for an efficient way to obtain this, either during the construction of the counter, or after it has been built.

Comment: You just asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20029048/1561176 - your desires are not clear it seems, since the previous question you asked has answers that answer exactly your question.

Comment: This is the same question asked second time

Comment: Actually this is not exactly the same question. I used the previous one to debug my code in order to understand what was my real problem. This question, instead, regards what is the problem that I have identified. Infact, in the previous question I was talking about one large list, while in this case I am considering different lists.

Comment: @markusian: And the `frozenset` solution offered by falsetru doesn't directly solve this problem too?

Comment: It could, but I am not sure if this is the most efficient solution I can find.

Comment: @markusian: just use `for lst in bigger_list`: c.update(map(frozenset, lst))` to add more counts to an existing `Counter` object in `c`.

Comment: @markusian: or use `itertools.chain()` to loop over all the tuples from all the lists as if it were one sequence.